# PHP Delete function broken

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

Im trying to get the delete function to work, however it is constantly failing. I have been looking at this for hours, and trawling the web looking for answers, but nothing seems to work. The idea is that in the table, there is a button to click. When clicked it will run the delete code on the row selected.

```
    <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

session_start();
if (isset($_COOKIE["user_cookie"])){
    $username = $_COOKIE["user_cookie"];     
}else{
    $username = '';
}
if (isset($_GET['New'])) {  
   Cookie("Event", $_GET['New']);  
}
if (isset($_COOKIE["user_type"])){
    $userType = $_COOKIE["user_type"];     
}else{
    $userType = '';
}


include_once('config.php');
if (isset($_GET['delID']) && true){ // COOKIE HERE

  $result = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM oneuuid WHERE uuid = " . $_GET['delID']); 
  if ($result === false){
    print("
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Failed to delete event')
      </script>
      ");
  }   
}




?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
  <title>UUID </title>  <!-- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!LOOK HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0" />
  <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
  <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">
  <link href = "loginstylesheet.css" rel = "stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css"> 

 .clickable{
      cursor: pointer; 
      cursor: hand;
    }
  .highcontrast {
      background-color: #696969;
      a, a:visited { color: white; }
    }  

  </style>
</head>






<body>
  <!--          div for toggle                             -->
  <div id="toggle" style="height:260px">
    <!--          div for toggle                             -->
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->  
 <div class="col-md-3" id="leftCol">
        <center>
          <form action = "printStuff2.php" method = "post">
            <input type = "text" name = "search" size="28" placeholder="Enter name..."/>
            <input type = "Submit" class="styled-button-8" value = "Search"/>
          </form>
        </br>
      </center>
      </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <!-- Main content on page -->
        <br>






      <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);


//search bar code.

//Establish connection
include_once('config.php');
      $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db); 
      if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
      } 
//variable to store user input, which we can work with.
      if(!empty($_POST['search'])){
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];



    //SQL Query, it selects all from DB where users input is similar to, either school name, headmaster name or address
        $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM oneuuid WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // if the $search contains at least one row
        print '<table class = "table table-hover">';
        print '<tr>';
        print '<th> SEARCH RESULT GENERATED </th>';
        print '</tr>';
        print '</table>';
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row from $result

          print '<table class = "table table-hover">';


            print '<tr>';

            print'<th> UUID</th>';
            print'<th> Name</th>';  
            print' <th> Delete </th>';            
            print '</tr>';

          while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

            print '<tr>';
            print '<td>'.$row["uuid"].'</td>';
            print '<td>'.$row["name"].'</td>';
            print("<td class='centered clickable' onclick='deleteEvent(\"$row[uuid]\", \"$row[name]\")'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></td>");            
            print '</tr>';

          }

           print '</table>';
        }
        else {
          echo '0 results';
        }
      }    
      ?>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Look UP!</div>
            <table class="table table-hover">


            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>








 <script type="text/javascript">


   function deleteEvent(uuid, name){
      if (confirm("You are about to delete \"" + uuid + "\" this can not be undone.") == true) {
        window.location.href = "printStuff2.php?" + "&delID=" + uuid;
    } 
  }




</script>


</body>
</html
```

Thanks

Comment: At what point is the problem occurring?  For example, have you verified that the delID is being passed to printStuff2.php successfully?  As a side, note, the syntax you're using for your delete command is open to sql injection.

Comment: What part of this isn't working?  Does the delete button appear?  Does its click event work?  Is your PHP page being loaded?  Are you getting the right value?  There's a lot going on here and "nothing seems to work" doesn't help us.

Comment: The code above, is the contnets of printStuff2.php. How would I go about protection from sql injection??

Comment: The row is not deleted, and the message displayed is:    alert('Failed to delete event')

Comment: @JoeM: See http://www.bobby-tables.com/.  P.S. If I went to `printStuff2.php?delID=uuid`, then your whole table would be emptied.

Comment: @JoeM: If your query failed, there may be an error.  Try to print that out: `if ($result === false){ echo $mysqli->error; }`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That shows that my query is wrong. On the where clause? It is only showing part of the coloum. The uuid coloum contains `315d71f2-d050-41e4-9639-f8032a5cc7ab` however, the error message shows `Unknown column '315d71f2' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @JoeM: That's because you are generating the following string: `DELETE FROM oneuuid WHERE uuid = 315d71f2-d050-41e4-9639-f8032a5cc7ab`.  You might want to put *quotes* around your string values.  P.S. See http://www.bobby-tables.com/php.html and follow the mysqli example.  Also see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Where am I adding them sorry? @RocketHazmat

Comment: @JoeM: You want your query to be: `DELETE FROM oneuuid WHERE uuid = "315d71f2-d050-41e4-9639-f8032a5cc7ab"`

Comment: @RocketHazmat sorry, to seem stupid, but I think iv tried every combination of positions for the quotes. No joy!

Comment: @JoeM: My advice would be to forget about the quotes.  Forget about building SQL queries by concatenating values into the string.  See http://www.bobby-tables.com/php.html and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and start using prepared statements.  `DELETE FROM oneuuid WHERE uuid = ?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending UUIDs, but not quoting them, so your query ends up being

```
  DELETE ... WHERE uuid=12345-6789-a0735...
                           ^---^--- numbers
                                     ^---unknown field name
```

Depending on the contents of the sections between the `-`, those are going to be treated as numbers or strings, which means you're doing mathematic subtraction, or specifying unknown/illegal field names.

You need at bare minimum:

```
DELETE ... WHERE uuid='$_GET[id]'
                      ^---------^
```

and really really REALLY need to learn about [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) before someone trashes your server.

Comment: So like:  `$result = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM oneuuid WHERE uuid =" ' . $_GET[delID]');`  ?? This returns a blank page as if something is wrong :(

Comment: @JoeM: `"DELETE FROM oneuuid WHERE uuid = '" . $_GET['delID'] . "'"`.  Watch your quotes.  Or better yet: `"DELETE FROM oneuuid WHERE uuid = '{$_GET['delID']}';`.